# Infinite strictly decreasing sequence of ordinals

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals, well-orders

I know that on a linearly ordered set $X$, $\leq$ is a well order if and only if $X$ contains no strictly decreasing sequence. However this conflicts in my head with the following problematic 'intuition' which I do not know where it fails.

Let $\alpha$ be a limit ordinal such that $\alpha\geq \omega_1$. All ordinals strictly less than $\alpha$ are a proper set and therefore we should not be able to find an infinite strictly decreasing sequence of ordinals. However since there uncountably many ordinals lesser than $\alpha$, it seems like we should be able to choose a strictly decreasing sequence in some complicated way. Aside from this proposition, can someone explain to me why a decreasing sequence must stablize?

I know there is probably some simple point which has not fully clicked for me.

Comment: "it seems like we should be able to choose a strictly decreasing sequence in some complicated way" Try actually doing that. Just saying that it seems like you should be able to isn't an argument, and the situation will become clearer if you try to flesh out exactly how you'd do this.

Comment: You also have an out and out error in your second paragraph: $\omega+\omega$ is a limit ordinal greater than $\omega$, and there are only countably many ordinals less than it. You have to go all the way to $\omega_1$ to find an ordinal with uncountably many predecessors, and uncountably many of those predecessors are limit ordinals.

Comment: You ought to play with some examples of countable ordinals, e.g. $\omega^\omega$, perhaps the simple point you are seeking will click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well. Choose $\alpha_0$, then maybe it was finitely many points below $\alpha$, but maybe it was infinitely many points below $\alpha$, i.e. there was a limit ordinal between $\alpha_0$ and $\alpha$.

Repeat the process. After finitely many steps you must have reached $\omega_1$, or went below it. Otherwise we had an infinite set of ordinals without a minimal element (that would be $\{\alpha_n\mid n<\omega\}$). Say that $\alpha_5$ was $\omega_1$. Now you have to choose a point below it, $\alpha_6$. But that's a countable ordinal, so you've discarded "most" ordinals already.

Rinse and repeat, and we hit $\omega$, say at $\alpha_{52}$, and then you have to choose $\alpha_{53}$ which is a natural number, and then there's only finitely many points left anyway. So your sequence had to be finite.

You might read my answer and object that I didn't really use the fact that it was $\omega_1$. And that's true. Because it's true for every ordinal. And it is one of those situations where "uncountable" is a red herring. Start with $\alpha_0=\omega$, there are infinitely many points below it, so principle dictates that we can find a decreasing sequence. But we can't, since after choosing just one we have only finitely many points to work with.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This is along the lines of the sort of explanation I was hoping for. Even though I think I need to digest this abit to appreciate the problem properly.

Answer (score 2):

This is a direct consequence of [the definition of a well-ordered set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-order) and [the definition of an ordinal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Definitions).
A linearly ordered set $(X, \leq)$ is *well-ordered* if and only if every nonempty subset $S \subseteq X$ has a least element.
Contrapositively, if we could come up with some infinite decreasing sequence $$x_1 > x_2 > x_3 > ... $$ of elements of $X$, then this would correspond to a nonempty, infinite subset $$S := \{ x_1, x_2, x_3, ... \} \subseteq X$$ with no least element, so $X$ would not be well-ordered.

Ordinal numbers, meanwhile, are typically **defined** to be certain well-ordered sets. In Von Neumann's formulation, for instance, any given ordinal is defined to be the well-ordered set of all smaller ordinals:

> *[A set S is an ordinal if and only if S is strictly well-ordered with respect to set membership and every element of S is also a subset of S.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Von_Neumann_definition_of_ordinals)*

So if I try to build my infinite descending sequence of ordinals starting from some infinite--even some uncountably infinite--ordinal number $\alpha$, I can't do it, because that sequence necessarily lives inside the well-ordered set $\alpha$, and as a subset of a well-ordered set, it has a least element.